Performance comparison of appending multiple files via Pandas, NumPy, Polars, CSV, parsers
What was done:
Evaluated performance of various parsers in NumPy, Pandas, Polars, CSV modules and standard Python routines for my application. I appended multiple (.txt) files into one single large file. Each combined file fits in memory (~46MB), has 1E6 rows of four floats, delimited by commas, as below:
12978.0,625730956116471.3275,843920.00,0.15
242553.0,875730956800704.2362,1737251.00,0.16
857385.0,891730956926730.5725,1697958.00,0.18
569484.0,258730957100957.8962,3285886.00,0.20
...

I have seen multiple articles and posts (like this) which mention that Pandas performs better when rows exceed 500K, so here I benchmarked the performance of various parsers.
Python script
import sys
import csv as csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import time
import os

# total files to append (file_0.txt,file_1.txt,...file_99.txt)
tot_files = 100
in_fl = 'file.txt'

# method-0 (pandas)
print('****Pandas****')
t_start0 = time.time()
fl_out = 'fl_pd.txt'
ln_pd = 0

with open(fl_out,'w') as f_w:
    pass

for fl_id in range(tot_files):
    rd_fl = f'{in_fl[:-4]}_{fl_id}.txt'
    rd_pd = pd.read_csv(rd_fl, chunksize=None, skiprows=2, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3],
                        names=['var0', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
    rd_pd.to_csv(fl_out, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
    ln_pd += rd_pd.shape[0]  # total rows read

print(f'*Total rows check: {ln_pd}')
print(f'*Time Taken-Pandas: {round(time.time() - t_start0, 1)} s\n')

# method-1 (numpy)
print('****NumPy****')
t_start1 = time.time()
fl_out = 'fl_np.txt'
ln_np = 0

with open(fl_out, 'w') as f_w:
    for fl_id in range(tot_files):
        rd_fl = f'{in_fl[:-4]}_{fl_id}.txt'
        events_np = np.loadtxt(rd_fl, delimiter=',', skiprows=2)
        np.savetxt(f_w, events_np, delimiter=',', fmt='%1.1f,%1.4f,%1.2f,%1.2f')
        ln_np += events_np.shape[0]

print(f'*Total rows check: {ln_np}')
print(f'*Time Taken-NumPy: {round(time.time() - t_start1, 1)} s\n')

# method-2 (python; row-by-row)
print('****Python (RowByRow)****')
t_start2 = time.time()
fl_out = 'fl_rBr.txt'
rBr_cnt = 0

with open(fl_out, 'w') as f_w:
    for fl_id in range(tot_files):
        rd_fl = f'{in_fl[:-4]}_{fl_id}.txt'

        with open(rd_fl, 'r') as f_r:
            for ln in f_r:
                f_w.writelines(ln)
                rBr_cnt += 1

print(f'*Total rows check: {rBr_cnt}')
print(f'*Time Taken-rBr: {round(time.time() - t_start2, 1)} s\n')

# method-3 (python; infile)
print('****Python (inFile)****')
t_start3 = time.time()
fl_out = 'fl_inFile.txt'

with open(fl_out, 'w') as outfile:
    for fl_id in range(tot_files):
        rd_fl = f'{in_fl[:-4]}_{fl_id}.txt'
        with open(rd_fl) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

print(f'*Time Taken-inFile: {round(time.time() - t_start3, 1)} s')

with open(fl_out, 'r') as f_r:
    inF_cnt = sum(1 for line in f_r)
print(f'*Total rows check: {inF_cnt}\n')

# method-4 (polars)
print('****Polars****')
t_start4 = time.time()
pls_cnt = 0
fl_out = 'fl_pl.txt'

with open(fl_out, mode="w") as f_w:
    for fl_id in range(tot_files):
        rd_fl = f'{in_fl[:-4]}_{fl_id}.txt'
        reader = pl.read_csv(rd_fl, separator=",", skip_rows=2, dtypes=[pl.Float64, pl.Float64, pl.Float64, pl.Float64])
        pls_cnt += reader.shape[0]
        reader.write_csv(f_w, float_precision=4)

print(f'*Time Taken-Polars: {round(time.time() - t_start4, 1)} s')
print(f'*Total rows check: {pls_cnt}\n')

# method-4 (csv module)
print('****Python (csv)****')
t_start5 = time.time()
fl_out = 'fl_csv.txt'
with open(fl_out, 'w', newline="\n") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for fl_id in range(tot_files):
        rd_fl = f'{in_fl[:-4]}_{fl_id}.txt'

        with open(rd_fl) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            csvwriter.writerows(csv_reader)

print(f'*Time Taken-csv: {round(time.time() - t_start5, 1)} s')

Performance summary:
Below is the time taken by each parser when appending 100 files. Polars stand out clearly. Any thoughts and comments on fundamental things happening at the back end?
*Time taken-Pandas: 945.7 s
*Time taken-NumPy: 1055.8 s
*Time taken-rBr: 3795.0 s
*Time taken-inFile: 155.8 s
*Time taken-Polars: 67.4 s
*Time taken-csv: 606.7 s


Do you really need to parse the files as csv into pandas dataframe/numpy array? I'd concatenate the files using just plain python (or bash script)

Thanks! I am aware of using the bash script, my question here is strictly knowing fundamental differences between two methodologies I followed and why Pandas is winning the game and not NumPy here?

@nuki neither pandas nor numpy are libraries where their primary use-case is "combine files". Pandas is for numeric calculations with labeled "tabular data", whereas numpy is for numeric calculations on multidimensional arrays. pandas uses numpy as a backend. The performance differences here probably come down to implementation details for the parsers. Neither is going to be particularly fast, and there is no general principle about numpy/pandas that you can extrapolate from this (except maybe that you probably should use the regular csv module)

Also, that answer you are relying on seems to be just making up this figure of 500k rows. pandas is never really faster than numpy -- it uses numpy -- although, it comes with some built-in routines that numpy may not have, and supports special data types that numpy doesn't have. Nowadays, pandas can use pyarrow as a backend, which may improve performance, particularly when working with strings

so, the answer to 2) pandas is in general not faster. what you are seeing here is the result of pandas having a better csv parser, but that really is not something either library is focused on providing. you will almost certainly have better performance using the standard library csv module to do the csv reading/writing, although, it isn't clear if you even need that, since you don't seem to be transforming the data in any way, so you could be even faster just using regular file handling with strings

When you wrote combine, I thought you making one large dataframe or array from many, but all you are doing is reading many csv, and writing each to an open csv, without saving or joining..  The only join is as successive lines of a text file.  The pandas csv reader is known to be relatively fast.  loadtxt used to be slow, python based, but recently has been rewriten into a compiled form that is faster.  But no data on how it compares to pandas.  np.savetxt is pure python, formatted line write. So this is really a csv read/write comparison.

side note: read about polars package, it should be much faster than pandas

@dankal444 do you think it will be much faster here? I'm skeptical but would be interested to see

@juanpa.arrivillaga my guess is yes, but a lot depends on what data is inside thos csv

I think since there is no actual modification of the csvs, an important point of comparison is 1) use the csv module 2) just use for line in fin: fout.write(line) The bottleneck here is almost certainly I/O

@juanpa.arrivillaga,@dankal444: I enjoyed reading your comments and thanks for the clarifications. As suggested by you folks, I benchmarked other parsers/routines and edited my post for future readers. Additional comments and thoughts on why one parser lags/leads the others?

Polars, DuckDB and pyarrow.csv are the 3 fastest CSV parsers I've tested (they're all multi-threaded) - Pandas also supports pd.read_csv(engine="pyarrow") instead of the default parser. It's not really clear what you're asking here though?

wow! polars is fast. But as I suspected, the csv module and just plain file handling beats both numpy and pandas.

!!! for the row-by-row, use f_w.write(ln) not f_w.writelines(ln)!!! and again, since there is no transformations or anything, read and write in binary mode, so 'wb' and 'rb'
